# Random Forest Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, data-analysis, grid-search

I'm trying to build a random forest classifier for binomial classification. Can someone explain why my accuracy scores vary every time I run this program? Scores vary anything between 68% - 74%. Also, I tried tweaking the parameters but I can't get the accuracy to go above 74. Any suggestions on this also would be appreciated. I tried using GridSearchCV but I managed only a decent 3 point increase.

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import preprocessing

#read data into pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

#handle missing values
df = df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'any')

#handle string-type data
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(['Male','Female'])
df.loc[:,'Sex'] = le.transform(df['Sex'])

#split into train and test data
df['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(df)) <= 0.8
train, test = df[df['is_train'] == True], df[df['is_train'] == False]

#make an array of columns
features = df.columns[:10]

#build the classifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier()

#train the classifier
y = train['Selector']
clf.fit(train[features], train['Selector'])

#test the classifier
clf.predict(test[features])

#calculate accuracy
accuracy_score(test['Selector'], clf.predict(test[features]))
accuracy_score(train['Selector'], clf.predict(train[features]))
```

Comment: link to dataset : https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/ILPD+(Indian+Liver+Patient+Dataset)

Comment: To improve you model I would suggest you to use ensembles and also try XGBoost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your accuracy changes every time you run the program because the model created is different. And the model is different because **you are not fixing the random state** when creating it. Have a look at the `random_state` parameter from the [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).

For your second question, there are many things you can try in order to improve the accuracy of a model. In order of importance:

- Get more training data
- Improve your training data (i.e. get rid of low quality features or samples, create new features ...)
- Tune the parameters of your learning algorithm (RandomForest has a few to play with)
- Try another learning model.
- Try combining different models

Comment: I was trying to tune the parameters, and ended up at : n_jobs = -1, n_estimators = 75, min_samples_leaf = 25, random_state = 42, oob_score = True. But still I get different values of accuracy : Out[472]: 0.75221238938053092, Out[474]: 0.68965517241379315

Comment: your train/test splitter is also random, if I read your code right (you could use `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` which takes a `random_state` argument)